# How to handle None type while splitting a column in Pandas into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, split

How to handle **None type** while **splitting a column in Pandas into two columns**

I have a column named 'TECHNIQUE' in the Data frame

```
Sample values = 'CALL VIA WEBSERVICES', 'EXPLOITATION VIA CAT TECHNIQUES', None, None
```

None = null value

I have to split the column 'TECHNIQUE' into 'TECH_PREFIX' and 'TECH_SUFFIX' using ' VIA '

if 'TECHNIQUE' is null I want to have null values for both the derived columns

I used the below code but getting **AttributeError**: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

```
df[['TECH_PREFIX', 'TECH_SUFFIX']] = df['TECHNIQUE'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' VIA ', expand = True))
```

Comment: `df[['TECH_PREFIX', 'TECH_SUFFIX']]  = df['TECHNIQUE'].str.split(' VIA ', expand=True)`  the `.str` is important here.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This worked, but if I give expand = False, I'm getting error like Columns must be same length as key. But I don't see any need for expand = True as I need to split only once. Please clarify

Comment: If you aren't expanding then you can only assign it back to a single column

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

```
df[['TECH_PREFIX', 'TECH_SUFFIX']] = df['TECHNIQUE'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isna(x) else x.split(' VIA ', expand = True))
```

If not working then try this;

```
df['TECH_PREFIX'] = df['TECHNIQUE'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isna(x) else x.split(' VIA ')[0])
df['TECH_SUFFIX'] = df['TECHNIQUE'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isna(x) else x.split(' VIA ')[1])
```

Comment: Hi, actually the correct solution is as given by @Chris above:
I was missing the series to str conversion. The split function handles np.nan by itself so no need to explicitly handle that. Thanks.